# How to see a lost control again?

Tags: winforms

I dragged the textbox to base panel and it disappeared completely. I can't see him. I made visible true and the Control is exists. If I make a new textbox I can't call it by the same name. I see him in Properties but not in Design. I have a lot of code on this control. How can I see the textbox again?

Comment: You can try manually removing the code for the textbox in the Form's designer.cs file, which won't affect the rest of the controls.

Comment: Is the TextBox visible in the Document Outline? (View > Other Windows > Document Outline;  Ctrl+Alt+T)  Is the TextBox a child of the panel?  Is the Panel set to AutoSize?  What is the Location of the TextBox control?  Can you share the relevant portions of `InitializeComponent` In your Form1.Designer.cs file?

Answer (score 0):

In the Form's designer.cs file, I added a deleted line.
   private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
And I added "this." Where it was deleted. (Compare to other controls that appeared in the Form's designer.cs file). Then the control returned.
Thank you for your help.